# Jersey class not found ... but it's there

Tags: java, spring, jersey

Followed the example from the jersey github, and getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer when running in Eclipse's embedded J2ee Preview server.

**What I've tried** (that had no effect)

Every website / SO post says to copy your libs into web-inf/lib. I'm using Maven so that's not an issues.

I've added the Maven dependencies to my deployment assembly as per yet another post suggesting to do so. (properties > Deployment Assembly)

The class it is complaining about exists in my classpath.

I'm using Jersey 2.x libs and not 1.x.

Eclipse -> Properties -> Maven -> "Resolve dependencies ...." is enabled.

**POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
        <artifactId>matching-engine</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>web</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>web Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.21</jersey.version>
        <spring.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.3</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>web</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**web.xml**

```
 <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Web</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.foo.web.conf.Application</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Web</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Why is it that I only see this problem with Eclipse users. I used to work with Eclipse, I can't stand it now. Moved on to Netbeans. Anyway, try to use the `maven-jetty-plugin` to run it. Just add [this plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html#get-up-and-running) to your `<plugins>`, then run `mvn jetty:run`. This will run your app in an embedded Jetty. I use it all the time for development,. If it works, then it is a problem with Eclipse

Comment: Thanks, but still same exception. Even tried with maven tomcat plugin.

Answer (score 1):

The error:

> NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContextListener

means that you are missing the `servlet-api` dependency. You are declaring a 3.0 webapp so you should add the dependency in version 3.0. Furthermore, that dependency needs to have a provided scope because it is provided by the server at runtime.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks. Feel kind of silly that I didn't think to check if it's getting pulled down. After patching that, I'm still getting a class not found on org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener, confirmed Maven is pulling down the spring-web jar and it is in there.

Answer (score 0):

(Credit where credit is due: Tunaki solved my first problem and I solved the second)

provided on the jersey-container-servlet dependency was causing problems. I removed it.